# Need some problem books in Topology with some special properties.

Tags: general-topology, geometry, reference-request, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I know there are lots of good books with good problems in Topology. But the problem with them is they are categorized into chapters. So, that gives away the hint of how to think, even if in general situation you won't naturally think that way about that problem. So, the books I want should have this following properties,-

1. They should not give the hint at first about how to think but would contain the hint/solution at the
   end in case I get stuck.(most probably it means problem books with only list of problems and
   solutions/hints but no chapters).
2. They should train me good enough in dealing with topological problems considering I will do PhD in
   Topology(General,Algebraic and Differential).
3. The hints and solutions should promote some kind of natural way of thinking most of the time.

Thank You.

Comment: I don't know if it suits you, but try to check out previous exams of topology exams. I think there are plenty of them online of several honorable universities

Comment: Look at the topology prelims/quals of a university of your choice.

Comment: 1) Click the `unaswered questions' tag on MSE. 2) ????. 3) Enjoy.